# Pass parameters from excel into script activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

Please help me with this: I was trying to read data from excel which has two columns by using lookup activity then i need to pass these value as the input of another script task by using for each loop but i am getting error-
The variable 'source_feed_id' of type 'String' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Array'. The variable 'source_feed_id' only supports values of types 'String'.

One column is of integer type and other is string

I read data of excel file through lookup activity then in foreach loop i use the output of lookup to run 17 times as the row count is 17-@activity('Lookup1').output.value

Then i use set variable to set the variable as the output of lookup activity with --@activity('Lookup1').output.source_feed_id

then the same i pass in script task as variable to update the table in sql

Answer (score 1):

When the value passed is not of string, then you will get this error.

[image]

In order to resolve this error,

- When connecting for-each activity with lookup activity, give the items expression as `@activity('Lookup1).output.value`

[image]

- Then inside for-each activity, in the set variable activity, give the value as  `@item().<column_name>`. Replace `<column-name>` with the required column name from lookup table. This column is not to be of array type. Otherwise, you will get the same error.

[image]

- Then you can use this variable `@variables('source_feed_id')` in the script activity to update the table.